# Python - Unrecognized Arguments: your_module.YourApi

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

If you are experiencing issues with an error that details Unrecognized Arguments than try this for a solution.

When executing the **endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java \ -o . your_module.YourApi** make sure to exclude the "\".

This solution worked for me and the .zip file was generated no problem.

New command from the root of the python project **endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java -o . your_module.YourApi**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. When executing the command endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java \ -o . your_module.YourApi, make sure you exclude the "\".

**endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java -o . your_module.YourApi**